# обфускация exe c#

Tags: c#

[image: Как мне адекватно сделать обф если eazfuscator легко крякать, а мне нужен другой обф]

Как мне адекватно сделать обф если eazfuscator легко крякать, а мне нужен другой обф , пожалуйста , можете мне скинуть обфускаторы которые поддерживают wpf проекты

Comment: https://enigmaprotector.com/ru (но тоже 50\50, вскрывается не особо сложно)

Comment: Любой .NET обфускатор вскрывается очень легко. Это бесполезно.